# Jquery mouseenter state show active state and disable no active

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseenter

Pretty strait forward:

- By default will always have 2 arrows displayed
  but on hover only the active one will have the arrow. On mouse leave the arrows will be displayed again.

Please have a look the demo, right now, the menu is always active

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/33qeqap3/1/

```
$('.subtext').mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).addClass('hover');

    if ($(this).hasClass('hover')) {
        $(this).addClass('yes');
    }

});

$('.subtext').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
    $(this).removeClass('yes');

});
```

Comment: I don't get it at all, why would the arrow be hidden, and why would it "stay" active? Seems to work exactly as expected to me !

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you add class subtext and you declare the after in your CSS it will never go away. You need to add a class with that stuff on demand in jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/33qeqap3/2/

Comment: Also, when you add a class, you don't really have to check if the element has that class on the next line, this makes less and less sense ?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want -> **http://jsfiddle.net/33qeqap3/3/**

Comment: "*both links should have the active state"* - what exactly do you mean by active state..?

Comment: @adeneo he wants to have both arrows shown when I'm not hovering it. But if I hover it I have only one with the arrow.

Comment: @VictorioBerra By default will always have 2 arrows displayed, but on  hover only the active one will have the arrow. On mouse leave the arrows will be displayed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$('a:not(:hover)')` to select the one that the cursor is not hovering over.

JS (jQuery):

```
$('a').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('a:not(:hover)').removeClass('arrows');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $('a:not(:hover)').addClass('arrows');
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/j89yhn3w/).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy a bit tricky I know, but with some css and a bit of js:

```
.hovered .arrow{display:none;}
.hovered.hover .arrow{display:block;}
```

**js:**

```
$('ul > li').hover(function(){
    $('a').addClass('hovered');
}, function(){
    $('a').removeClass('hovered');
});


$('.subtext').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
})
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/33qeqap3/5/

Answer (score -1):

Everything is functioning as intended but your psuedo selector is selecting the base element as opposed to the hovered element, adjust the CSS as follows:

```
.subtext.hover:after{
    content:">";
    position:absolute;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jebv6yb3/)